# Sql Server 2005 Dev Edition Not connecting on Windows 2003 Server from Win 7

Tags: sql-server-2005

Management Studio of Sql Server Dev Edition 2005 installed on Win 7 is not able to connect on Windows 2003 Server where standard edition of sql server 2005 is installed.

The connection is working when I use the Sa password but when I use windows authentication then it is showing err msg that "user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection"..

I'm using a local admin password on win 7 and in passwords server password is saved (i.e. the domain password), I'm even able to get exchange mails so domain pass is working fine from other places but sql server is not able to connect..

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are not used while using windows authentication :) Your client computer credentials need to be trusted by SQL server - this is easiest to achieve for domain (Active Directory) accounts.

You need 1) login into your dev computer as domain user 2) add same domain user (or containig group) to sql server permitted logins for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply on this..

I got the final answer and below is the link for the same..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/291024fe-5ba7-4872-b0f0-8fc0c78578bc/